# Get calendars of office365 email without authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, office365

I want to get list of events of particular users lets say user@company1.com , user@company2.com which uses office365 accounts.

I need to retrive user@company2.com calendar with out login. My application will be like listing my available timings for my clients , so that they can select my free time and will schedule meeting with me. I need to filter the already scheduled events from my list... Is there any example code for getting calendar events without login??

I tried office365 multi-tenant application which will gives sample code for getting calendar events only after login. I need it with out authentication. Please help me on this.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding 'without login', that would be a terrible security flaw. Would *you* want anyone to be able to look at your calendar? Your application would need *something* to give it permission to access the calendars.

Comment: Yes , In my website it will be like http://mywebsite.com/user1/meetings.. In this URL i can show USER1 available times. I need to filter the timings of already scheduled events. Here user1 will not login to office365...

Comment: That entirely depends on which calendars you're accessing. Will you be showing user1 their own calendar? Or will you show user2's calendar to user1? What group do these calendars belong to? If you want user1 to see the organization's calendars, you can simply have the organization give your application a authorization token, so that it can do the authorization, without requiring your users to login to office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried to use the free/busy code. My code is as follows... I am following this procedure but I don't know if it is correct or not. I have a Microsoft Office 365 account, and by passing credentials silently, I am creating Exchange Server service. After that i am passing different domain attendee information as ORGANIZER and REQUIRED as follows. But it is returning all values not skipping any scheduled meetings for those users.

Lets assume *user1@domain.com* is ORGANIZER and *user2@anotherdomain.com* is REQUIRED for meeting . User1 have meeting scheduled at 7:00-7:30pm on daily basis but when I executed the following script it shows me 7:00-7:30pm as available for meeting. It supposed to block that time.

Can you suggest some changes to code and am I proceeding in the correct way?

```
private static void GetSuggestedMeetingTimes(ExchangeService service)
{


    List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();

    attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
    {
        SmtpAddress = "user1@mydomain.com",
        AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer
    });

    attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
    {
        SmtpAddress = "user2@anotherdomain.com",
        AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required
    });

    // Specify options to request free/busy information and suggested meeting times.
    AvailabilityOptions availabilityOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
    availabilityOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49;
    availabilityOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
    availabilityOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 40;
    // Note that 60 minutes is the default value for MeetingDuration, but setting it explicitly for demonstration purposes.
    availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration = 30;
    availabilityOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good;
    availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
    availabilityOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;

    // Return free/busy information and a set of suggested meeting times. 
    // This method results in a GetUserAvailabilityRequest call to EWS.
    GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                     availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow,
                                                                     AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
                                                                     availabilityOptions);
    // Display suggested meeting times. 
    Console.WriteLine("Availability for {0} and {1}", attendees[0].SmtpAddress, attendees[1].SmtpAddress);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (Suggestion suggestion in results.Suggestions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Suggested date: {0}\n", suggestion.Date.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("Suggested meeting times:\n");
        foreach (TimeSuggestion timeSuggestion in suggestion.TimeSuggestions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0} - {1}\n",
                              timeSuggestion.MeetingTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                              timeSuggestion.MeetingTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration)).ToShortTimeString());



        }
    }

    int i = 0;

    // Display free/busy times.
    foreach (AttendeeAvailability availability in results.AttendeesAvailability)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Availability information for {0}:\n", attendees[i].SmtpAddress);

        foreach (CalendarEvent calEvent in availability.CalendarEvents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tBusy from {0} to {1} \n", calEvent.StartTime.ToString(), calEvent.EndTime.ToString());
        }

        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to access the O365 information without authentication is impossible , either user authentication or app authentication will be required . In your scenario ,you may need app authentication . You could try to build Daemon or Service Apps using client credential grant flow as described in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/), the service app that requires admin consent, but is authorized to access any mailbox/calendar information in your Office 365 tenant.

Another choice is to use EWS Managed API, you could get free/busy information of a user and suggested meeting times by using the EWS Managed API :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673(v=exchg.150).aspx

And an existing Office add-in support on Outlook:

https://findtime.microsoft.com/

Comment: This link worked for me... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx .... But i need to get available timings between 9AM - 5PM. How can i get that?

Comment: @user3463733 Try to filter the returned results client side . The GetUserAvailability method supports only time periods that are a minimum of 24 hours long and that begin and end at 12:00a.m. To restrict the results of the method to a shorter time period, you must filter the results on the client .

Comment: Can you suggest some code for filtering these times ?